# What is the inverse Lapalace transform of $\frac{e^{1/s}}{s}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Don't solve it fully. Give me some hints to begin with. I tried one approach: Since we know $L[\int_{0}^{x} f(x) dx]=\frac{F(s)}{s}$ if $L[f(x)]= F(s)$. Thus I only need $L^{-1}[e^{1/s}]=g(x)$. And then $\int_{0}^{x} g(x) dx$ is the required inverse Laplace transform. But $g(x)$ does not exist because $\lim_{s\to\infty} e^{1/s} \neq 0$. So this doesn't work. I understand that I need to treat this $\frac{e^{1/s}}{s}$ as a whole. WolframAlpha returns $I_0(2\sqrt{x})$ as the answer which I can't even understand. What is that $I_0$? Please help me out.

**EDIT:** I am not allowed to use the expression for $L^{-1}f(x)$ as mentioned in one answer below. We aren't taught modified Bessel function also. What I can use: definition of Laplace transform, Laplace transform expressions for elementary functions, inverse Laplace transform by inspection  (i.e. using the Laplace transform in reverse, basically observation), exponential shift, Convolution.

Comment: $I_0$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1). You could try to Laplace transform the differential equation for this Bessel function and see that $e^{1/s}/s$ is a solution of it.

Comment: @Raskolnikov : If I know the D.E. whose solution is this, does it help me find its Laplace inverse?

Comment: Do you want to use expansion $e^\frac1s=1+\dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{1}{2!s^2}+\dfrac{1}{3!s^3}+\dfrac{1}{4!s^4}+\cdots$ then
$$L^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{s}e^\frac{1}{s})=1+\sum_1\dfrac{t^n}{(n!)^2}$$

Comment: @MyGlasses : Does linearity work on infinite series. I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Could someone confirm whether linearity of Laplace transform works on infinite series or not? I was told that it doesn't. An explanation too would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Wolfram Alpha tells you what $I_0$ is:

[image]

Secondly, note that by definition:

\begin{align}
I_0(x) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{1}{t} e^{\frac{1}{2}x(\frac{1}{t}+t)} dt \\
\mathcal L^{-1}f(x)       &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \frac{1}{s}
e^{\frac{1}{s} + sx} ds\end{align}

Observe what happens to the second integral after the transformation $s = \frac{t}{\sqrt{x}} $. After that think about why the line integral must be equal to the path integral around the origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I am not taught all of that. Please check the EDIT in the question.